# Extracting specified number from char array

Tags: c++, c, scanf

Trying to extract seconds from next string using sscanf:
Now it's 2013-12-04 18:01:20

`sscanf(buf, "%*s %*s %*d%*s%*d%*s%*d %*d%*s%*d%*s%d", &i);`

And it fails, any ideas how to make proper format for it? Or any ideas to extract it easier? All I need is last second.

Comment: "It fails" ......

Comment: This question is tagged [C++] and [C]. Which language are you using? Anyway, this should help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf (the part about the `%s` flag would be a good place to start with what's wrong with your code)

Comment: Check out `strptime` if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sscanf("Now it's 2013-12-04 18:01:20", "%*s %*s %*s %*d:%*d:%d", &i)
```

Comment: So the ':' symbols isn't a string. Thank you:)

Comment: @Vanguard: `%s` matches a string up to the next leading whitespace. The problem is not that `:` isn't  a string, but rather that `:01:20` **is** a string (and so is `-12-04`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (1 == sscanf("Now it's 2013-12-04 18:01:20", 
    "Now it's %*d-%*d-%*d %*d:%*d:%d", &i)) Success();
```

Comment: I prefer this because it checks that the expression matched as the variable `i` could contain any value +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strrchr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr) which looks for the last occurrence of the passed char.

```
    char * now =  "2013-12-04 18:01:20";
    char *ptr = strrchr( now, ':' );
    int i=0xFF; /* out of acceptable values ;) */
    if( ptr ) {
       i = atoi( ptr+1);
    }
```